# Spring Security: Page does not redirect after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've built a webapp from scratch using Spring boot and Java. Now I want to integrate Spring Security into the system.

However, I'm having problem with logging in using Spring Security. I used a customize login page and I had configured it correctly. Not sure what am I missing.

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.security"}, basePackageClasses = {LoginController.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.auth.repository"})
public class CpexProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CpexProjectApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLogin() {
    return "login";
}

}
```

**Security Config**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/scss/**","/vendor/**","/img/**","/js/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/home/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()  
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home/**")
            .permitAll();
}

private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return charSequence.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

}

**Custom class of UserDetails**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

public CustomUserDetails(final User user) {
    super(user);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return getRoles()
            .stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return super.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return super.getName();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

**application.properties**

```
#CPEX database - UAT
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.2.254;databaseName=ROOT
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#View Resolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

#Bean Override
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#For detailed logging during dev
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

#Tomcat default port
server.port=8888
```

**login page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>CPEX - Login</title>

<!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
<link type="text/css" href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

<div class="container">

<!-- Outer Row -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">

    <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image border-right border-3">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/sbc-logo.png" alt="">
          <div id="loginSuccessAlert" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">
              <strong>Login Successful!</strong> 
          </div>
          <div id="loginDangerAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
              <strong>Please check your credentials.</strong> 
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="p-5">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 display-4">CP Exchange</h1>
              </div>
              <form id="loginForm" class="user" action="home" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Username...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" />
                <hr>
              </form>
              <div class="text-center">
                <a class="small" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
  <!--   <script src="js/custom/validateLogin.js"></script> -->

</body>

</html>
```

**home page**

```
code is too long
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> optionalUsers = userRepository.findByName(name);

    optionalUsers
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
    return optionalUsers
            .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
}
}
```

TIA

Comment: .defaultSuccessUrl("/home") with GetMapping("/home")

Comment: Tried this, however, same thing still happens. Page gets redirected again to login even I had entered the admin credentials.

Comment: antMatchers("/home/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home");

Comment: Still the same. Nothing happens upon clicking login.

Comment: HELP please.....

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed your Login JSP Submit will trigger `/home` which you have configured as `defaultSuccessUrl` and it will return Login page as you are not yet logged in.

Please change below line in your login.jsp

```
<form id="loginForm" class="user" action="home" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form id="loginForm" class="user" action="perform_login" method="POST">
```

Also you can remove this line

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/home/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

and add

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
```

from configure method for now just to try.

If it works go ahead and add other configuration one by one.

```
http
    .cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**","/scss/**","/vendor/**","/img/**","/js/**").permitAll() 
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()  
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login") // add Login submit url
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home/**")
        .permitAll();
```

EDIT 1:

If you are using `inMemoryAuthentication` add `userDetailsService` as well like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())
        .withUser("admin").password("aaa11111").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("user").password("bbb22222").roles("USER"); 

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

Comment: Tried this as well, however, the page gets redirected to localhost:8888/login?error

Comment: This is what appeared in the console upon setting logging to TRACE level: w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Comment: Tried changing configure method in web security config class to this:  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
         .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())
         .withUser("admin").password("aaa11111").roles("ADMIN")
         .and()
         .withUser("user").password("bbb22222").roles("USER");

Comment: Still no luck, though.

Comment: try inMemoryAuthentication with no passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())  .. I think passwordencoder is messing things

Comment: Tried removing passwordencoder but same thing happened got redirected to localhost:8888/login?error with same error in logs (bad credentials)

Comment: On a side note, I checked the console and I saw this: o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User '' not found. Could it be that the value was not passed properly from user interface?

Comment: Please add CustomUserDetailsService  class also in post

Comment: Still the same (bad credentials). I noticed that User '' not found is still prominent after the system had showed the query that was used.

Comment: Better you remove inMemory and try with DB User only. 
There is some issue with query. User Repository is not able to find any user. 
Try to remove password encoding from config and keep plane password in DB password field and try.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. My config is literally just this right now: auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); Still, I'm getting the same error. Might take a look on jdbcauthentication